# Add a new key-value to a json string

Tags: apex, json

The scenario is as follow, I got a json which was converted to a string, I need to add to that json another key-value pair.

I assume it requires to convert the string back to json, how would that work?

Class_A:

```
List<String> jsonStrings;
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('_id', '1234');
gen.writeStringField('title', '2345');
gen.writeEndObject();
jsonStrings.add(gen.getAsString());
Class_B classBinstance = new Class_B(jsonStrings[0]);
```

Class_B:

```
public Class B(String json){
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    //TODO: get the json string from Class A, convert it back to json and add to it another key-value pair
}
```

Comment: Could you update your post with what you have tried and the problem you are facing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can pass json generator object directly to class b.

```
public class Class_B{
    JSONGenerator gen;
    Class_B(JSONGenerator gen){
        this.gen = gen;
    }
}

List<String> jsonStrings;
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(false);
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('_id', '1234');
gen.writeStringField('title', '2345');
gen.writeEndObject();

Class_B classBinstance = new Class_B(gen);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, since I was required to add only two fields I decided to resolve it by manipulating the string and not the json:

```
public String addKeyValuetoJson(String json,string newValue, Boolean isNew){
    String temp;
    if(!isNew) { 
        temp = json.removeEnd('}');
        temp=temp+',"_rev":"'+newValue+'","status":"update"}';            
    }
    else{
        temp = json.removeEnd('}');
        temp=temp+',"status":"new"}';
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Basically, I removed the end of the string '}' and concatenate what I needed.